# Handlebar.js Conditional comparison to {{this}}

Tags: javascript, templates, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

I'm using the following helper to allow me to do conditional comparisons:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifCond", function (v1, operator, v2, options) {
  switch (operator) {
  case "==":
    return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  case "===":
    return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  case "<":
    return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  case "<=":
    return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  case ">":
    return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  case ">=":
    return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  default:
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

Then I have my template setup like this:

```
<select name="mode">
    {{#each data.modes}}
    <option {{#ifCond data.curmode '==' this}} selected="selected" {{/ifCond}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I'm passing in `data` which is an object containing `modes` (a flat array of modes available, strings) and `curmode` which is a string containing the currently selected mode.

As far as I can tell everything is being passed in fine - I can display the `data.curmode` and each of the `data.modes` populates correctly. However, it's not outputting the `selected="selected"` on match.

Comment: What does the data that you're feeding to the template look like?

Comment: `data` is an object, it contains 2 properties: `modes` (the array of modes) and `curmode` which is a string with the current matching mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an iterator, such as `#each`, everything inside the block is referenced with respect to the current element. So, if you say this:

```
{{#each a}}
    {{x}}
{{/each}}
```

Handlebars will look for `x` within the current value of `a` rather than in the global namespace for the template. So you need to look outside the `{{#each data.modes}}` value if you want to get at the top level `data.curmode`:

```
<select name="mode">
    {{#each data.modes}}
    <option {{#ifCond ../data.curmode '==' this}} ...
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

The `../` steps you up one level.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Sz6VT/

Comment: Thanks! I actually have this in another module, not sure how I missed it. Nice explanation.